# I don't really know javascript closure

Tags: javascript, closures

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FTtENLSjMNHfElhHiXlk?p=preview).

```
function factory() {
    var yscale = function() {
        console.log("original");
    };
    var status = {
        yscale: yscale
    };

    function render() {
        yscale = function() {
            console.log("I am a scale");
        };
    }

    render.__privateStatus = {
        yscale: yscale
    };

    render.__privateStatus2 = status;

    render.__privateStatusGetter = function() {
        return status;
    };

    render.__privateStatusGetter2 = function() {
        return yscale;
    };

    return render;
}

var chart = factory();
chart();
console.log(chart.__privateStatus.yscale); // "original"
console.log(chart.__privateStatus2.yscale); // "original"

console.log(chart.__privateStatusGetter().yscale); // "original"
console.log(chart.__privateStatusGetter2()); // "I am a scale"
```

I returned a function in a closure, if some initialization happens in closure function, what the reason preventing the new value revealed as status of the returned function?

Could anyone help explain this from the language itself?

## Update

Base on @RobG's answer, I think the question could be simplified with

- **Is function a primitive type?**
- **What's the difference between a function and an object?**.

You could noticed that yscale is a function(it is undefined before the call of chart(), even initialize yscale with a function, result is the same).  If function is primitive type, we should not be able to attach properties to it.  If function is an object, we possibly could use the reference passing to change it status.

I know my second question is kinda naive. If you define a function and let a variable point it,  you cannot simply **change its inner states** by assign it to another function.  But think my first question--we could change a function(or function pointer)'s states by attaching method to do like render.__privateMethods to change its behaviors.

Everybody knows we could use a module pattern to use an object to return the API of a module.  Mike Bostock shows [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) that we could use a function to achieve similar thing just as an object and even more, we could have something like a constructor.  I thought I know both function and object very well. But with some wild thoughts, I am confused.

That's the reason I am looking for an answer from javascript language rather than what the result should be even from instinct.

Comment: The script works as it should work. What do you want to now precisely? Why `chart.__privateStatus.yscale` returns `undefined`?

Comment: Yes.  At my understanding, all un-primitive type value should pass reference.  Why yscale is not the new value we changed in the execution of  chart()? Or why the yscale here is not really closed in closure. I know this would work. 

     function render() {
         status.yscale = function() {
            console.log("I am a scale");
          };
    }

Comment: Please show what you expect to occur and what actually occurs. I see exactly what I expect, so a statement like "*what the reason preventing the new value revealed as status of the returned function*" is meaningless.

Comment: @RobG, I am expecting the updated yscale after the invoke of the closure returned function. I know using `status.yscale` in the `render` function will work. With the basic idea about closure, the `yscale` should also attached to the closure context.   Maybe I am just confused, but I still feel there are something fun with closure, function and object here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a guess that you're surprised that the following returns *undefined*:

```
console.log(chart.__privateStatus.yscale);
```

That is because when the following line is executed:

```
render.__privateStatus = {
        yscale: yscale
    }
```

the value of the *yscale* variable is *undefined*, so that's the value that gets assigned. Changing the value of the variable later has no effect. Note that in javascript, assigning a primitive assigns the actual value, assigning an object assigns a reference to the object. So while `__privateStatus` is passed a reference to the object, the *yscale* property is assigned the actual value *undefined*.

For the same reason:

```
console.log(chart.__privateStatus2.yscale);
```

returns undefined because there is:

```
var yscale;
var status = {
    yscale: yscale  // yscale is undefined when this assignment is made
};
```

so *status.yscale* is undefined and later:

```
render.__privateStatus2 = status;
```

is assigned a reference to the same object. Changing the value of *yscale* later has no effect, its previous value has already been assigned.

Same again for:

```
console.log(chart.__privateStatusGetter().yscale); // undefined
```

To get the current value of *yscale*, change the function to:

```
render.__privateStatusGetter = function() {
    return yscale;  // use closure to variable to get current value
}
```

then:

```
console.log(chart.__privateStatusGetter());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have reorganized my followup thoughts in the question. I will keep the answer unresolved till I found find the answer of the origin of function and object.  I will revisit some book to find the answer as well.